# "How to establish TCP connection with multiple IPs from single client C# application"

Tags: c#

I had developed a C# TCP Client application to connect multiple IPs simultaneously or concurrently. I had programmed my application in such a way that, application will create thread for each IP and establish connection with the same and after finishing its job, that particular thread will be killed. The same thing will happen for all threads. (For Eg. If my application needs to connect 100 IPs simultaneously, 100 threads will be created for each IP. Every thread will be killed once they are done with their job). I had mentioned my code for thread creation below. I just wanted to know whether I'm going in a right way. Is this way of my approach is good? Please guide me in this regard. Thanks in advance

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < IPsCount; i++)
{
    try
    {                
       Thread serverThread = new Thread(Service);
       serverThread.Start(IP_Add);    
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Every thread will be killed in Service method after finishing their job.

Comment: what is `IP_Add` ? it doesn't seem to have a per-iteration value... how many IPs are there? thread-per-socket doesn't scale well, so whether that is OK or not depends on the number of sockets; why are you sleeping between sockets?

Comment: If it does go wrong `ex.ToString();` isn't going to help you..

Comment: @MarcGravell i am curious on how is it possible to have a single thread with many stream socket working at the same time. Do you know of any docs on how a single thread can read many incoming network packet at the same time ? Just asking as i am actually still on the lookout for better implementation of my large server farm control.

Comment: @Franck you don't have a "a single thread with many stream socket working at the same time" - you have *zero* (dedicated) threads, using async IO with worker completion callbacks; that's basically how anyone with large connection counts should usually be working; `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is a good place to start looking, although these days you may be better served by looking at "pipelines"

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks buddy. Will take a good look at that `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. Pipeline i am already doing this to locally on the computer to communicate with the many processes (NamePipe) but over the network it doesn't connect due to IT shenanigan.

Comment: @Franck named pipes != pipelines; completely different thing

Comment: Like others wrote one thread per connection in general is a bad design decision for several reasons. One reason is that there's a limit on how many threads can be created because stack-memory is limited. Another reason is that at some point thread switching will cost you more performance than a single thread or threadpool solution. When you want to know more about the performance issue google for "context switch".

Answer (score 0):

I would store all IP-Adresses in a collecton and do
[Paralell.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8). Should be easier and saves you all the bare-metall thread handling :-)

**UPDATE after discussion in comments:**

I understood the OP that each connection is used for a short period, that is query some data then close. Then my method is good. 
For long running tasks do create threads on your own or go to a boss-worker modell.

Comment: or you could do `await Task.WhenAll(ipAddresses.Select(a => ...));`

Comment: Is that really a good idea? I mean `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't guarantee that it'll use one thread per ip right? It puts them into smaller batches which will then be processes in parallel so you'd still have multiple IPs in one thread. The idea of spawning a new thread for each IP is to be able to interact with each endpoint in parallel. Having batches of less but still multiple endpoints wouldn't allow that right? Only one could be processed at the time.

Comment: @Joelius no, I agree that this **is not at all** a good idea; `Parallel.ForEach` is intended for short-lived operations, not long lived things like ongoing connections; this would be a great way to block the thread-pool by saturating the threads

Comment: That depends on what the work that needs to be done is. I understood the  OP that the work is short and completed soon. You are absolutley right that this is not the way to go for long-running work - I updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below.

This code is an untested attempt at using `System.IO.Pipelines` to achieve your goal.

It should be a much better starting point than using `Thread.Start` directly.

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly IEnumerable<IPEndPoint> ipAddresses = new[]
        {
            new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8087),
            // more here.
        };

        internal static async Task Main()
        {
            await Task.WhenAll((await Task.WhenAll(
                    ipAddresses.Select(OpenSocket)))
                .SelectMany(p => p));

            // Handling code in ProcessLine.
        }

        private static async Task<IEnumerable<Task>> OpenSocket(
                EndPoint iPEndPoint)
        {
            var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            await socket.ConnectAsync(iPEndPoint);
            var pipe = new Pipe();

            var attendants = new[]
            {
                FillPipeAsync(socket, pipe.Writer),
                ReadPipeAsync(socket, pipe.Reader)
            };

            return attendants;
        }

        private static async Task FillPipeAsync(Socket socket, PipeWriter writer)
        {
            const int minimumBufferSize = 512;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Request a minimum of 512 bytes from the PipeWriter
                    var memory = writer.GetMemory(minimumBufferSize);

                    var bytesRead = await socket.ReceiveAsync(
                             memory,
                             SocketFlags.None);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    // Tell the PipeWriter how much was read
                    writer.Advance(bytesRead);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Make the data available to the PipeReader
                var result = await writer.FlushAsync();

                if (result.IsCompleted)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Signal to the reader that we're done writing
            writer.Complete();
        }

        private static async Task ReadPipeAsync(Socket socket, PipeReader reader)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var result = await reader.ReadAsync();
                var buffer = result.Buffer;
                SequencePosition? position;

                do
                {
                    // Find the EOL
                    position = buffer.PositionOf((byte)'\n');

                    if (position == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var line = buffer.Slice(0, position.Value);
                    ProcessLine(socket, line);

                    // This is equivalent to position + 1
                    var next = buffer.GetPosition(1, position.Value);

                    // Skip what we've already processed including \n
                    buffer = buffer.Slice(next);
                } while (position != null);

                // We sliced the buffer until no more data could be processed
                // Tell the PipeReader how much we consumed and how much we
                // left to process

                reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

                if (result.IsCompleted)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            reader.Complete();
        }

        private static void ProcessLine(
                Socket socket,
                in ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer)
        {
            Console.Write($"[{socket.RemoteEndPoint}]: ");

            foreach (var segment in buffer)
            {
                Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(segment.Span));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```